# stack-upgrade: Stack 1.5.1 to latest version

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to upgrade my stack version. Currently I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on a VM, and my stack version is 1.5.1 which I downloaded using sudo apt haskell-stack (I was trying to run stack setup (using the latest version) to compile a program, where stack was not found so it recommended me to install it via this method). However, I am wanting to upgrade it to the latest version. This is what I get when I run stack upgrade:

```
Current Stack version: 1.5.1, available download version: 2.3.3
Newer version detected, downloading
Querying for archive location for platform: linux-x86_64-static
Querying for archive location for platform: linux-x86_64-
Downloading from https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/releases/download/v2.3.3/stack-2.3.3
linux-x86_64.tar.gz

Downloading complete, testing executable
Version 2.3.3., Git revision cb44d51bed48b723a5de08c3348c0b3ccfc437e x86_64 hpack-0.33.0
WARNING: Installation path /home/claraina/.local/bin not found on the PATH environment variable
New stack executable available at home/claraina/.local/bin/stack
```

I've also tried running `curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh` which tells me that 'Stack Version 1.5.1 already appears to be installed at: /usr/bin/stack' and refers me to stack-upgrade again. I'm new to stack, so any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like stack was upgraded in a user-local way. Essentially, now you have two `stack` executables installed: one in `/usr/bin` and one in `/home/claraina/.local/bin`.

That is fine. To run the new stack, you have to be sure that your `PATH` has the directory `/home/claraina/.local/bin` before `/usr/bin` in it, so that the new stack is run instead of the old one.

Run `echo $PATH` to check your path. Then, if needed, [edit `.bash_profile` accordingly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path).

After you edit that file, either log out & log in again, or start a login shell to reload the changes (for that shell).